# How would I implement a Gatekeeper bypass in my Swift 5 macOS app?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift5, osx-gatekeeper

My app requires `sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine (app directory here)` to be run in order for it to boot up on my tester's Mac. Is there a way to implement this into the app so that the command isn't needed?

I have to reach into the Downloads folder for the app, so I assume that's what's setting off the Gatekeeper alarm bells.

Comment: If there were a way to do that within the app, malware authors would be able to bypass it that way as well, negating the purpose of Gatekeeper. Are you subscribed as an Apple developer? If so, get Developer ID signing certificates, and sign and notarize the app. If not, you might be able to send them the app in a way that doesn't trigger quarantine (it's not due to the Downloads folder, but to the program that put it there). You could also make a droplet or something to remove the quarantine xattr.

Comment: I distributed it through Google Drive as a .zip. Do you think that could've been the reason why? If you have any alternatives for distribution please let me know. I'm also not a developer, it's a little too pricey for my small development needs :P

Comment: Are you saving them in Google Drive, and then downloading them with a browser? If so, it's the browser applying quarantine. If it's something like syncing via a directly shared folder, then I'd guess Google Drive is doing it (but I haven't tested to see if Google Drive does).

Comment: I would upload the app to my Google Drive, and my tester would then download the zip file that is created. Now that I'm thinking about it it's probably macOS seeing that it's an app from a browser so it trips quarantine. I'll look into other ways to get the app to them.